# Do I only need to check the users machine for the version of the MSVCR90.dll that was installed with my python installation?

Tags: python, py2exe, msvcr90.dll

I was working on an update to my application and before I began I migrated to 2.62 because it seemed to be the time to.  I walked right into the issue of having problems building my application using py2exe because of the MSVCR90.dlls.  There seems to be a fair amount of information on how to solve this issue, including some good answers here on SO.

I am deploying to users that more likely than not have 32 bit XP or Vista machines.  Some of my users will be migrated to 64 bit Vista in the near future.  My understanding of these issues is that I have to make sure they have the correct dlls that relate to the version of python that exists on the application development computer.  Since I have an x86 processor then they need the x86 version of the dlls.  The configuration of their computer is irrelevant.

Is this correct or do I have to account for their architecture if I am going to deliver the dlls as private assemblies?

Thanks for any responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vista 64bit has a 32 bit emulator I believe, so you will not need to worry about this.

However, I would just tell them to install the msvcrt runtime which is supposed to be the correct way to deal with this sxs mess.

Comment: Thanks but my understanding is that if they install the msvcrt runtime they will get the dlls native to their operating system in the sxs directory.  When I installed it in a test machine I only ended up with one of three possible versions.  If I have to install them I have to figure out how to get the other two versions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered and learned the correct answer is that I have to worry about the MSCVCR90 dll that is used in the version of Python and mx that the application I am building rely on.  This is important because it means that if the user has a different configuration I can't easily fix that problem unless I do some tricks to install the correct dll.  If I have them download the MS installer from MS and their hardware (CPU type) does not match mine then they will potentially run into problems.  There is a really good set of instructions on the wxpython users group site.  [WX Discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/wxPython-users/browse_thread/thread/7f01edf7349b9ec1/dfad0122afda5d21#dfad0122afda5d21).